# Why does shutter speed on my D7000 change after every shot in manual mode?

Tags: shutter-speed, nikon-d7000, manual-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nikon D5100 M Mode (Manual) settings reset for every shot whilst the camera pointing to the same object](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22753/nikon-d5100-m-mode-manual-settings-reset-for-every-shot-whilst-the-camera-poin)

My D7000 is not working properly.  No matter what lens I have attached to the camera body, when shooting in manual mode, the shutter speed changes itself after every shot.  And not just a little, it makes drastic changes.  Why is that?  Is there a setting to turn that off?  The shutter speed should remain unchanged unless I change it.  The aperture stays consistent in manual mode, but not the shutter speed.  Please tell me how to fix this.  Perhaps I have a defective unit.  In fact, shutter priority and aperture priority are also having issues.  I will take one shot that comes out fine, not change anything with conditions staying the same, and the next shot is way over exposed.  Please help.  This is getting frustrating.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Check if you have exposure bracketing turned on.  That's the only thing I can think of that would cause that.

If so, it will cycle through a number of exposures, then back to your original setting, and repeat.

There should be a Bkt button on the left side of the front of the body as you look down on the camera (if it's the same as D90).  Push that in, then rotate the rear thumbwheel and set it to 0F (again based on D90, might pay to check your manual)

Failing that, you should be able to reset your camera to factory defaults by pressing two buttons (which have green dots next to them) simultaneously and holding them for two seconds.