# How can I get 5 bracketed exposures with a D90 for HDR without screwing around?

Tags: hdr, nikon-d90, bracketing

My D90 only brackets one exposure each + and - (3 total). Anyone doing HDR with a D90, or other limited camera, how do you get 5 exposures without a lot of screwing around? I really don't want to touch it once the tripod is set. I would like 5 shots that are 2 stops apart.

Comment: Related: [Why do most cameras only support 3 frames of auto exposure bracketing?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27326/why-do-most-cameras-only-support-3-frames-of-auto-exposure-bracketing)

Comment: Tether the camera and change the shutter speed from the computer.

Comment: @MichaelClark Can you suggest some particular software for control? I have never tethered. I have a turntable that can control the camera. I should look at the protocol. I could make a little Arduino "Bigger Bracketer" dongle.

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer http://nikonrumors.com/2013/05/11/free-open-source-tethering-software-for-nikon-dslr-cameras.aspx/

Comment: There's also a list of other previously reviewed software for tethering to Nikon cameras at the bottom of the article. You can even get iPhone and Android apps now, but I'm not sure if any will work with the D90.

Answer (score 4):

What I personally do is use the exposure compensation. (I have a Canon myself, so exposure compensation for me is just one flick at the big wheel. For your camera you need to press a button in combination with a dial, so  it is a little bit more cumbersome). Set the exposure compensation to -2 for your first batch. Then you get three shots:

-4 -2 0

Then set the exposure compensation to +2 and start your next batch. You then get the shots:

0 +2 +4

So you end up with one double shot, but you have 5 shots with two stops between them. It might not be what you are looking for; you still have to touch the camera between the two batches. Nevertheless I think this is the minimal effort to do it in-camera.

Comment: If your canon is supported by Magic Lantern just install that...

Comment: Nope, it isn't ;)

Comment: bummer, it works well.

Comment: Thanks @mmumboss that is pretty straight forward and with the alignment algorithms in HDR software the touching should not be a problem when I can take the extra time.